# Pure JS validation always returning false in mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, validation

I have the following code which works fine in desktop but in mobile device it fails. Even if the full name field is not empty, it gives the same alert.

```
function validateForm() {

    var full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;

    if (full_name == '') {
        alert("Please enter your full name.");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/yx5Mb/6/

Comment: go home, you´re drunk :)

Comment: Yeah that could be the case, even the day favors that ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
function validateForm() {

    var full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;

    if (full_name == '') {
        alert("Please enter your full name.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If condition fails you are not returning `true`.

Comment: Ahh...stupid I am...but still it doesn't work in mobile.

Comment: Well that's all I have...It's pretty simple but doesn't work in mobile...I don't think the problem is in the code.

Comment: action is missing in your html ?

Comment: Tested with action..still it's not picking up the value.